# new construction wiring a mid-line receptacle to a switch

Tags: electrical

how do you wire a mid-receptacle to a switch? I have 3 receptacles running with a switch to the mid receptacle.

Comment: Welcome to the stack exchange. Could you help us by giving more detail on what you want to do are you trying to control.1  outlet with power to another.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the receptacle will be wired as in Fig. 1.  To control the receptacle with a switch, you should wire it as in Fig. 2.

[image]
<sup>Grounding conductors not shown</sup>

Notice that the switch is interrupting the "hot" wire.  Also notice that the white wire leading to the switch is simply capped off.  This is because code may now require that a neutral be present at switch locations. If this is not required for your installation, you can use two wire cable instead. If you use two wire cable, make sure you reidentify the white wire by marking it at both ends with black tape or marker.

Comment: Your drawing is awesome (particularly the way it addresses "how do you draw white wires").  They sing songs about your code prowess, so I reluctantly say I'd rather see that marked white wire be a red wire, and a white wire brought up and capped.  It's good practice generally, $2 future-proofing, and will spare you an argument with the inspector about whether that switched outlet load is a lighting load.  It is if there's no overhead light in the room, or if it's removed.

Comment: @Harper you're right. There should be a neutral at the switch, as per code. Sometimes I forget, as it's a new requirement. Updated.

Comment: It is a good idea to have one there, even though the Code is clear that it isn't required for receptacle loads (404.2(C)(7)) -- there *are* cases where "smart switching" of receptacles is desirable.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel You're right, updated.